# Ascending Order is not Working in Custom Post Type Listining

Tags: custom-post-types, order

Can you please let me know why this code is not listing Custom Post Types?

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query(
              array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => 'ne',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                    )
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 10
              )
         );
?>
<?php 
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
echo '<ul>';
 while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
 $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
 echo '<li>'.the_title().'</li>';
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the custom post type `'product'` by title, please try:

```
 array( 'post_type'       => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'  => 10, 
        'orderby'         => 'title',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
             array( 'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                   'field'     => 'slug',
                   'terms'     => 'ne',
                  )
         )
      )
```

where `'field'` can in general be  either `'id'` or `'slug'` ([ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)).
You can check the available `orderby` input parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).